# Embed a Window into Another

Tags: c#, wpf

I have two WPF applications which I wrote myself, App1 and App2. I wish to embed App2 into App1.

Currently, I am trying this:

```
App2 app2 = new App2();
object content = app2.Content; //which is a grid
app2.Content = null;
mainGridOfApp1.Children.Add(content as UIElement);
```

It does appear, but there's a few problems:

- It is not displayed correctly; the button locations and other UIElements are all messed up.
- It covers the entire screen, although mainGridOfApp2 is fixed at a much smaller size. The effect is like `WindowState.Maximized`.
- I have applied a custom style (theme) in App2, but since App2's App.xaml is not read, the custom style is not applied. How do I apply it?

How do I embed App2 into App1 seamlessly? I do not want to start App2 as a separate process and setting App1 as the parent because that would mean it would always be on top of whatever UI component App1 have.

**EDIT:**
I have embedded App2 into App1. I put the main grid of App2 into a `UserControl`, and loaded the `UserControl` from the Window. For App1's side, all I did was call the `UserControl` of App2 after referencing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can load App2 assembly into your App1 application and create an instance of the Window/UserControl that you want to display in the content.

You'll need to make some changes to the App1 so that you can reference the types or maybe create a common assembly with the required interfaces you can tie them together with.

Think any solution (which doens't involve App2 having its own process and being hosted) will rely on changes to the source code.